# Adobe Brackets + jQuery file type

Tags: jquery, file-type, adobe-brackets

I've recently started learning jQuery and I ran into the problem that the Brackets editor (my favorite one) does not recognize the syntax of this language and puts JavaScript [file type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtnQL.png) by default, which creates a lot of errors.
How can I deal with it?

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript. What kind of errors are you seeing?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/2XaLCFW.png

Comment: Thats a JSLinter not liking the formatting and not Brackets not understanding the JS.  You should check into how to modify the code styles you want your linter to inspect - or remove the linter until you know why it exists.

Comment: It's just the linter not understanding because it hasn't been configured. If your relative paths and orders are correct, the code should still fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know what you mean... I’ve found that Brackets only recognizes jQuery when you include the library in the file; that is, when you: a) paste the whole library on top of your script (which obviously is inefficient and has a lot of drawbacks) or b) write it in an html file with the script linking to jQuery before the script of your code. Either way, Brackets will understand the syntax as it is now being defined in the same document. 
In short, as far as I know, it can only be done in HTML

Comment: I’m not sure if there is any plugin that allows for jQuery syntax functionality though... if there is, I think that would be the way to go.